# Robustness in panel regression analysis

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am running a fixed effects panel regression as under

$y=a+bx+e,$

where y=dependant variable, $x$=control variables, $a$=individual effects, $b$=slope, $e$=error term.

I first ran the FE panel regression with variables in levels (that is without taking logarithm). Then I ran the FE panel regression with variables expressed in logs. Ideally since taking logs is just scaling of the variable, we should not expect any change in the sign and statistical significance of the coefficients, b. But I find that for some control variables, the coefficients have changed when I take the logs. Am I going wrong somewhere? Which version gives correct results?

Comment: Can you show us a subset of the values for your control/outcome variables? Are some of the values between 0 and 1?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes That is true. Here are the some of the values

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes That is true.But I have not taken logs of dummy variables or categorical variables. Here are the some of the values             
country_id 1
year             2006
crar           0.0844
tier1_cap_rwa 0.0935
RoA 0.1183
RoE 0.1139
z_score 0.1238
reg ranges between 0 and 1
accept_dep ranges between 0 and 1
country ranges between 0-1
ofc 0-1
country_type  1-3
real_st_rate 0.16234 
ef1_gdp 0.4900399
ef2_gdp 0.0595650
ef3_gdp 0.0000000
ef4_gdp 0.0035492
ef5_gdp 0.2157386
act_restrict 8
entry_req 7
cap_reg 6
ff 0.077
rol_index 1.77
rol_rank 0.10

Comment: Your comment is somewhat inscrutable. Could you post your output? Also, which variable are you logging?

Answer (score 0):

Log-transforming a value *less than* 1 results in a negative number. Here is a quick demonstration in R:

```
# Generating a sequence of values between 0 and 1 (inclusive), incrementing by 0.1

x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
x
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

# Taking the log() of each value in this sequence

round(log(x), 2)
[1]  -Inf -2.30 -1.61 -1.20 -0.92 -0.69 -0.51 -0.36 -0.22 -0.11  0.00
```

It is entirely possible for the sign of a [Pearson's correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) to flip as a consequence of logging observations between 0 and 1. In such contexts, it's possible for $\rho(X,Y)$ to flip sign if we $\log X$ or $\log Y$, or both. See below for a quick-and-dirty simulation. In each iteration, I assessed the correlation between 10 pairs of values. The correlation was preserved in 7 out of the 10 trials. Note, upon each draw of 10 observations, a subset fall between 0 and 1, which reverse in sign *after* the log transformation; this has the potential to influence the relationship between variables.

```
set.seed(13)

sims <- 10
levels <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 10)  # storage for the numeric values in levels
logged <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 10)  # storage for the "logged" numeric values

for (i in 1:sims) {
  x <- exp(rnorm(10)); y <- exp(rnorm(10))       # drawing 'positive' random deviates             

  levels[i] <- cor(x, y)                         # correlation in levels
  logged[i] <- cor(log(x), log(y))               # correlation of the logged values
}

flipped <- (levels > 0 & logged < 0) | (levels < 0 & logged > 0)
preserved <- !flipped

# Were the correlations between pairs preserved?

cbind(levels, logged, flipped, preserved)

           levels      logged flipped preserved
 [1,]  0.10728307 -0.01369591       1         0
 [2,]  0.93652958  0.62956976       0         1
 [3,]  0.01300703  0.07601658       0         1
 [4,] -0.06794333  0.37656387       1         0
 [5,]  0.17978986  0.27654877       0         1
 [6,]  0.19476326  0.54571601       0         1
 [7,] -0.09462134 -0.04706490       0         1
 [8,] -0.25225396 -0.40215868       0         1
 [9,] -0.20694668 -0.05695933       0         1
[10,] -0.04839709  0.08447948       1         0
```

Another example is when a transformation *dampens* an outlier that was exerting major leverage. Review the top answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383581/interpretation-of-%ce%b2-in-case-of-log-lin-model-for-relationship-between-x-and-y/383750#383750) for a very simple and clear demonstration of this. If you're working with per capita *rates* (e.g., limited number of incidents per unit population) or *proportions*, then a log transformation can influence or even reverse the sign of a coefficient.

Comment: If the matter is statistically argued, we can never establish robustness in our regressions.  The whole objective of a doing an regression with economic variables is to establish causality. If it lacks robustness just by log transformation, no referee will ever accept a paper.

Comment: Your question was focused on your coefficients and how a log transformation might affect the *sign* of the observed effect. Why did you log transform your control variables in the first place? Was it to facilitate interpretation? Did the levels have a discernible skew?

Comment: I think it may have to be statistically argued, especially when you’re log-transforming values less than 1.

Comment: I have already mentioned I am not log transforming values less than 1. It is against econometrics principle to do that.

Comment: @indumann I would update your post and show us the distributions of the variables you logged. This way we can diagnose the problem more precisely. I will adjust (remove) my answer if it doesn’t apply to your situation.